# '10' a string is being broken into 1,0 when itertools combinations used

Tags: python, string, casting, python-itertools

I have a list of a sequences given as strings such as `['0',.....,'10']`. When I use `itertools.combinations` to get a combination of 2s such as `('0','2')`, I notice that the `'10'` isn't being counted as a single entity.  I.e. I don't see a `('2','10')`, instead I see a `('2','1','0')` or any combination with `10`. It is being considered as `1,0` and then the combinations are being formed. I would appreciate a fix for this. I did consider converting the format to int but I want to keep forming larger combinations such as `(1,2,3)` after forming length 2 combinations.

```
def frequentPattern(data, minsup):
    frequentSets = []
    itemset = {}


    for line in data:
        for c in line.replace(',','').split():

            if itemset.get(c)==None:
                itemset[c]=0
            itemset[c]+=1

    k = 1
    while itemset != {}:
        prevCandidates = []
        print itemset.keys()
        for i in itemset.keys():
            print i
            if itemset[i] >= minsup:
                prevCandidates.append(i)
                if i not in frequentSets:
                    frequentSets.append(i)

        candidates = []
        for i in itertools.combinations(prevCandidates,2):
            cell = tuple(set(i[0]+i[1]))
            #print cell
            #cell = tuple(sorted(cell))
            if len(cell)<=(k+1):
                candidates.append(cell)
        candidates = list(set(candidates))

        itemset = {}
        for line in data:
            for cell in candidates:
                if set(cell) <= set(tuple(line.replace(',','').split())):
                    if itemset.get(cell)==None:
                        itemset[cell]=0
                    itemset[cell]+=1

        k = k+1
    return frequentSets
```

As noted the problem was with the cell = tuple(set(i[0]+i[1])) line. Do you see a way around it? The objective of that line was to create combinations of length greater than 2.

Comment: It would be useful if you could share the code you actually have

Comment: I cannot replicate this problem.  Using `list(combinations([str(x) for x in range(8,11)],2))` gives the expected result of `[('8', '9'), ('8', '10'), ('9', '10')]`

Comment: Posting an image is bad juju.  Are we supposed to retype it to try it???  cut-n-paste!

Comment: Just discovered this community. I apologize for not being familiar with the proper formatting.

Comment: From your code, `cell = tuple(set(i[0]+i[1]))` is breaking it up.  `i` is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`itertools.combinations` is working properly.  You are breaking up the result with `cell = tuple(set(i[0]+i[1]))`.  That adds the two strings (e.g. `'910'`) then breaks up the digits.  `i` has the correct result of, for this example, `('9','10')`.

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are using it correctly. I assume you are trying something along the lines of

```
from itertools import combinations

a = [str(i) for i in range(11)]
print(list(combinations(a, 2)))
```

In this case, the string '10' is not broken into '1' and '0'. The output will have 55 values, including ('0', '10'), ('1', '10')... ('9', '10')